# How to position DIVs relatively to the browser window?

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I have a PHP page that displays me the content of a conversation and allows me to answer back. As messages are displayed in inverse chronological order (newer messages are showed first), positioning the "Answer" form at the end of the page would look bad and not comfortable to use (one has to scroll between all messages), but positioning it on the top looks bad too, as one cannot read old messages and answer back.
So, I need something like Facebook does for conversations: one can read all messages while the textbox remains at the fixed position. An example may be found [here](http://www.akamai.com/html/technology/dataviz2.html): when entering the page [and waiting a few seconds], an image on the left appears, and follows the browser as you scroll the page.

Comment: Are you just looking for the CSS property [`position:fixed`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Fixed_positioning)?

Comment: Do you mean `position:fixed`? In your link I don't see any image on the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [`position:fixed` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position).

HTML:

```
<textarea class="inputbox"></textarea>
```

This CSS will put it at the bottom of the page:

```
.inputbox {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

You probably also want to look at `top`, `left`, and `right`.

Answer (score 1):

use can use position:fixed on div and adjust it with top , left or bottom, right or whatever  that you want to choose